# Suggestions on good reference books for Markov Chains suited to my purpose

Tags: probability, reference-request, markov-chains, book-recommendation

I am a currently a student pursuing Masters level course in Data Science.

I am taking a first course on Markov Chains this semester.

I am currently referring to the class handouts and the text book [Finite Markov Chain and Algorithmic Application by OLLE Haggstrom](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/finite-markov-chains-and-algorithmic-applications/EE10AF27811B43B02E05905DC6413467).

However, I am really struggling to get an intuitive feed of certain topics.

Could you suggest a more elementary book that slowly builds and spends time on some of the following topics:

1. Stationary distribution, Initial distribution( I know the concept, but problems are twisted, so better, deeper understanding is needed)
2. Total Variation distance
3. Poincare Constant,Poincare Inequality, Cheeger Constant
4. Update functions.
5. Reversibility

Or in general a source, which covers these topics with but in a more intuitive way with plenty of examples. I am a computer science undergrad and this is one of the first mathematical courses that I am taking.

Cheers!